# What should I do if fclose fails?

Tags: c, file, io

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp = fopen("hello.txt", "r");
    
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fputs("hello.txt failed to open\n", stderr);
        return 0;
    }
    
    /* do some stuff with the file */
    
    if (fclose(fp) == EOF) {
        /* what should I do? we can't just leave a file open */
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

`fclose` can fail, but if it fails to close a file, what should I do? We can't just leave a file open. Do we keep closing the file until it doesn't fail? What would you guys do?

Comment: If the file was opened for reading, there is no remedial action worth taking. Note that any open file will be closed by the system on program exit.

Comment: If you are in a hosted environment, don't stress. Your program isn't responsible for fixing all the problems in the system it runs on. You can print a descriptive error to stderr, and then exit the process with a code signalling failure.

Comment: Use `fflush()` for points where you need to write to the file.

Comment: On Linux, at least, the manpage for the underlying `close(2)` call says not to retry after an error, fwiw.

Comment: And more importantly, looks like the standard says that using the FILE pointer for anything after `fclose()`, whether it returns an error or not, is undefined.

Answer (score 3):

Any usage of the `FILE` pointer after calling `fclose()` on it (Regardless of if `fclose()` indicates an error or not) is undefined behavior*.

So the best you can do is log the error and have your program continue. Depending on what it does, exiting with an error status is also an option.

---

* Section 7.21.3 of the C11 draft says:

> The value of a pointer to a FILE object is indeterminate after the associated file is closed

And the [POSIX documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fclose.html) says:

> After the call to `fclose()`, any use of `stream` results in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

An error on `fclose` does not mean that the system refused to close the file. It should seldom happen on files opened for reading, and then it can only be a consequence of a hardware failure or a major bug in the filesystem or kernel, not things that a normal program should deal with: just log or report the error if you can. And anyway, after calling `fclose` the handle should never be used again, whether an error occured or not.

But when files were opened for writing and buffering is used, an error on `fclose` can arise if the last writing operations that are still queued could not complete. Here the cause can be a quota exceeded error, file system full or any other error which could be reported by `fwrite`. So in that case an error on `fclose` could be processed the same way you handled the errors on the previous `fwrite`. Neither more, neither less, except that you can no longer use the file handle.

Answer (score 1):

The description of `fclose` in the standard says:

> 2. A successful call to the `fclose` function causes the stream pointed to by `stream` to be flushed and the associated file to be closed. Any unwritten buffered data for the stream are delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; any unread buffered data are discarded. Whether or not the call succeeds, the stream is disassociated from the file and any buffer set by the `setbuf` or `setvbuf` function is disassociated from the stream (and deallocated if it was automatically allocated).

So if `fclose` fails, then it is not exactly guaranteed that the file handle was recycled, or the file was closed properly, but `FILE` pointed to by `stream` cannot be used any more, because the file was disassociated from it and the buffers deallocated.

Note that `fclose` can fail for example if some data was held in buffers and the disk runs out of space. If you care about the data being written correctly, use `fflush` to flush the data, and handle errors from it, for example prompt the user to reclaim more disk space or similar; unlike `fclose`, you can always try to retry `fflush` later.